# Dialog Back Press Disabled

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am working on the app and I am stuck at one position. I am using a custom dialog to display messages. When my dialogue box pops up to display message I set all the views which are showing on the activity as Invisible so it looks good while my dialog box is open there are no background views. One way to dismiss the dialog box is to click on the OK button which will set the views that are present on the activity back to VISIBLE condition.
**The problem** what I am stuck in is what if user press back button instead of OK button, that will cause the dialog box to diaper but the views are still hidden. I tried to disable the back button but it is not working. It works if the user presses the back button twice not one.

[Image before the dialog box appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsAH2.png)

[Image when the dialog box appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5NWJ.png)

[Image when user click back button instead of OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN4JK.png)

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.alexeducationchina.alexeducation.App;
import com.alexeducationchina.alexeducation.R;
import com.alexeducationchina.alexeducation.UserAgreement.UserAgreement;
import com.backendless.Backendless;
import com.backendless.BackendlessUser;
import com.backendless.async.callback.AsyncCallback;
import com.backendless.exceptions.BackendlessFault;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView memberRegister ;
    private EditText firstName , lastName , email , password ;
    private Button register ;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences ;
    ValidateInformation validateInformation ;
    private CardView cardFirstName , cardLastName , cardEmail , cardPassword , cardRegister ;
    private ImageView userImage ;




    private void linkWithXml () {

        memberRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.memberRegister);
        firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);


        cardFirstName =(CardView) findViewById(R.id.FNC);
        cardLastName =(CardView) findViewById(R.id.LNC);
        cardEmail =(CardView) findViewById(R.id.EC);
        cardPassword =(CardView) findViewById(R.id.PC);
        cardRegister =(CardView) findViewById(R.id.RC);

        userImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userImage);


    }

    private void settingFonts() {

        firstName.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getRegularFont());
        lastName.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getRegularFont());
        email.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getRegularFont());
        password.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getRegularFont());
        memberRegister.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getBoldFont());
        register.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getBoldFont());

    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        linkWithXml();
        settingFonts();
        register.setOnClickListener(this);
        App.getAppInstance().initApp();

    }







       /*



*/



       private void hideViews () {

           userImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           memberRegister.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           cardFirstName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           cardLastName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           cardEmail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           cardPassword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           cardRegister.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


       }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId()==R.id.register){


            hideViews();
            validateInformation = new ValidateInformation(Register.this , "REGISTER");
            validateInformation.register(firstName , lastName , email , password);



       //     startActivity(new Intent(Register.this , UserAgreement.class));

        }


    }

    private void showViews () {

        userImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        memberRegister.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cardFirstName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cardLastName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cardEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cardPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cardRegister.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }


}


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.alexeducationchina.alexeducation.App;
import com.alexeducationchina.alexeducation.R;
import com.alexeducationchina.alexeducation.UserAgreement.UserAgreement;
import com.backendless.Backendless;
import com.backendless.BackendlessUser;
import com.backendless.async.callback.AsyncCallback;
import com.backendless.exceptions.BackendlessFault;

public class ValidateInformation {


    Context context ;
    ImageView ui ;
    TextView rt ;
    CardView fn ;
    CardView ln;
    CardView e ;
    CardView p ;
    CardView r ;
    ProgressBar progressBar ;
    TextView notice ;
    LinearLayout linearLayout ;

    private static String userOk = "NOT" ;
    ValidateInformation(Context context , String activityName){

           this.context = context ;
        progressBar = new ProgressBar(context , null , R.style.ProgressBarTheme);
           if (activityName.equals("REGISTER"))
           {
         ui = (ImageView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.userImage);
         rt = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.memberRegister);
         fn = (CardView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.FNC);
          ln = (CardView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.LNC);
         e = (CardView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.EC);
         p = (CardView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.PC);
        r = (CardView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.RC);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
           }
    }


    public void register(EditText firstName , EditText lastName, EditText email , EditText password){


        String FIRST_NAME = firstName.getText().toString().trim();
        String LAST_NAME = lastName.getText().toString().trim() ;
        String EMAIL = email.getText().toString().trim() ;
        String PASSWORD = password.getText().toString().trim() ;

        String emptyFirstName = "Enter Your First Name";
        String emptyLastName = "Enter Your Last Name";
        String emptyEmail = "Enter Your Email Address" ;
        String emptyPassword = "Enter Your Password";
        String allEmpty = "All The Fields Are Empty";
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(FIRST_NAME) && TextUtils.isEmpty(LAST_NAME) && TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL) && TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD))
        {

           showMessage(allEmpty);

        }



        else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(FIRST_NAME)&& TextUtils.isEmpty(LAST_NAME) && TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL) && TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD))
        {
            showMessage(emptyLastName+"\n"+emptyEmail +"\n"+emptyPassword);

        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(FIRST_NAME)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(LAST_NAME) && TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL) && TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD))
        {
            showMessage(emptyFirstName+"\n"+emptyEmail +"\n"+emptyPassword);


        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(FIRST_NAME)&& TextUtils.isEmpty(LAST_NAME) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL) && TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD))
        {
            showMessage(emptyFirstName+"\n"+emptyLastName +"\n"+emptyPassword);


        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(FIRST_NAME)&& TextUtils.isEmpty(LAST_NAME) && TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD))
        {
            showMessage(emptyFirstName+"\n"+emptyLastName +"\n"+emptyEmail);


        }




        else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(FIRST_NAME)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(LAST_NAME) && TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL) && TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD))
        {

            showMessage(emptyEmail +"\n"+emptyPassword  );

        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(FIRST_NAME)&& TextUtils.isEmpty(LAST_NAME) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD))
        {

            showMessage(emptyFirstName+"\n"+emptyLastName  );
        }



        else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(FIRST_NAME)&& TextUtils.isEmpty(LAST_NAME) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL) && TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD))
        {
            showMessage(emptyLastName+"\n"+emptyPassword  );



        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(FIRST_NAME)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(LAST_NAME) && TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD))
        {

            showMessage(emptyFirstName+"\n"+emptyEmail  );
        }


        else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(FIRST_NAME)&& TextUtils.isEmpty(LAST_NAME) && TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD))
        {

            showMessage(emptyLastName+"\n"+emptyEmail  );

        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(FIRST_NAME)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(LAST_NAME) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL) && TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD))
        {

            showMessage(emptyFirstName+"\n"+emptyPassword  );
        }


        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(FIRST_NAME)){


            showMessage(emptyFirstName);
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(LAST_NAME)){

            showMessage(emptyLastName);
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL)){
            showMessage(emptyEmail);

        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD)){
            showMessage(emptyPassword);

        }



        else {

            showRegisterViews();
            showProgressBar();
            hideRegisterButton();

            BackendlessUser user = new BackendlessUser();
            user.setProperty( "email", email.getText().toString().trim() );
            user.setPassword(  password.getText().toString().trim() );

            Backendless.UserService.register( user, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>()
            {
                public void handleResponse( BackendlessUser registeredUser )
                {
                    hideRegisterViews();
                    hideProgressBar();
                    userOk = "OK" ;
                    showMessage("You Are Registered");
                    notice.setText("CONGRATULATION");
                    linearLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context , R.drawable.upper_rounded_congratulation));



                }

                public void handleFault( BackendlessFault fault )
                {
                    hideRegisterViews();
                    hideProgressBar();


                    switch (fault.getCode()){




                        case "2002" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("Invalid Application Info (Application Id Or Api Key)");

                            break ;


                        case "3009" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("User Registration Is Disabled For The Application");

                            break ;


                        case "3010" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("User Registration Has An Unknown Property And Dynamic Properties Are Disabled For This Version Of The Application");

                            break ;


                        case "3011" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("Missing \"password\" Property");

                            break ;


                        case "3012" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("Required Property Is Missing");

                            break ;


                        case "3013" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("Missing Value For The Identity Property");

                            break ;


                        case "3014" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("External Registration Failed With An Error");

                            break ;


                        case "3021" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("General User Registration Error. Details Included With The Error Message");

                            break ;


                        case "3033" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("User With The Same Identity Already Exists");

                            break ;


                        case "3038" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("Missing Application-Id Or Collection Of Properties For The Registering User");

                            break ;


                        case "3039" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("Property \"id\" Cannot Ce Used In The Registration Call");

                            break ;


                        case "3040" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("Email Address Is In The Wrong Format");

                            break ;


                        case "3041" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("A Value For A Required Property Is Missing");

                            break ;




                        case "3043" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("Duplicate Properties In The Registration Request");

                            break ;
                        case "8000" :

                            userOk = "NOT" ;
                            showMessage("Property Value Exceeds The Length Limit");

                            break ;





                    }



                }
            } );




        }
        }




        private void hideRegisterButton () {

        r.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
        private void hideProgressBar (){

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        private void showProgressBar () {


        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        }

    public void showMessage(String message){



        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.validation_purpose);

        notice = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitle);
        TextView information = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.information);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);


        Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);

        information.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getRegularFont());
        information.setText(message);


        notice.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getBoldFont());

        ok.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getBoldFont());

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (userOk.equals("NOT")){

                }

                dialog.dismiss();
                showRegisterViews();

                if (userOk.equals("OK")){

                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context , UserAgreement.class));
                }


            }
        });


        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        dialog.show();

    }

    private void showRegisterViews(){


        ui.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ln.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        e.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        r.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



    }
    private  void hideRegisterViews (){


        ui.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        rt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ln.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        e.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        p.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        r.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }




}
```

What i want is when user click back button nothing should happen or to block the back button i have already used the

```
onBackPressed()
```

method but it work only if user tap the back press twice.
**What is did** 
I declare views visibility as VISIBLE when back press is click the views comes back after twice back presses and problem is then i cannot go back to my previous activity other approach i did is to declare the method that bring the views back by declaring 
`onRestart()`
but failed 
I really appreciate if anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: You can use a DialogFragment instead of your Dialog. Override `onDismiss()` in the DialogFragment and notify the hosting Activity (have it implement some kind of custom `interface Listener{ void onMyDialogDismissed();}` See for example this post on [Using DialogFragments](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)

Comment: try using `dialog.setCancelable(false);` and `dialog.setCancelOnTouchOutside(false);` to disable back button presses for your dialog

Comment: You have used the view in a complicated way, please use single parent view from register screen for hide and show.
and the best solution is to use dialog fragment with full screen, then you need not call view show and hide.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with this. This will disable the back press button and it works like a charm.

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            return keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK;
        }
    });
```

Comment: By disabling the back button, you are forcing users to register or to quit your app completely (home button). This is considered bad design, see the [quality guidelines](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/core-app-quality), specifically position UX-N2 "All dialogs are dismissible using the Back button."

Comment: Actually, I am forcing user only when dialog popup is shown so they can click only on ok to dismiss the dialog

Comment: Yes, and if you want to follow the quality guidelines  (for example if you need to publish on Google Play) you should allow users to dismiss every dialog by pressing the BACK button. That's why I suggested using a DialogFragment.